# How samskaras are manifested as per Vedanta philosophy?

Tags: philosophy, vedanta, samskara

How exactly the latent impressions that are submerged in our subconscious, arise at the surface of our conscious mind. I know they arise as vrittis or thought waves, but what triggers them to rise in the first place? ... Some say it's our desires that awakens or manifests the samskaras ... but i always thought that once samskaras and memories arise as vrittis, they give rise to desires and those desires forces us to act in a certain way.

Can someone please explain how the samskaras arise, how the desires arise, and how the memories arise? In other words, which happens first or which gives rise to which? Thnx.

Answer (score 2):

Krishna says in the Gita 2.62-3 (Swami Nikhilananda translator):

> When a man dwells on objects, he feels an attachment for them. Attachment gives rise to desire, and desire breeds anger.
>
> From anger comes delusion; from delusion, the failure of memory; from the failure of memory, the ruin of discrimination; and from the ruin of discrimination the man perishes.

And in 3.36-37:

> *Arjuna said*: But under what compulsion does a man commit sin, O Varshneya, in spite of himself and driven, as it were, by force?
>
> *The Lord said*: It is desire, it is wrath, which springs from rajas. Know that this is our enemy here, all-devouring and the cause of all sin.

The senses are being bombarded by outside stimuli all the time. We can close our eyes, but even when we don't want to hear, we hear. Krishna says it all starts when we dwell on the these stimuli.