How does the mind-soul find a suitable host?
I read the following here:

When our habit patterns become so ingrained that they alter our body
chemistry, it is called “addiction.” When they become strong enough to
alter our thinking process, it is called “samskara.” At this stage we
no longer remember when or how this process started. And without
introspection or retentive power we fail to discover the realm of the
mind where these samskaras are stored. When our mental world is
totally under the influence of these powerful impressions they become
the determining factors of our personality, and due to these samskaras
we perceive this world in our habitual ways.

Let's assume the mind continues in whatever form after death, and the samskaras are part of the package.  Now when it comes time to select the potential karma (the gunas), the samskaras are playing a vital role, right?  What does the mind care?  It is obliged to choose for the improvement of karma or for more fun and games? How do gunas evolve from samskara?  What is the process?
The reason I ask, I wear prescription eyeglasses.  I have had them since the 3rd grade.  I have Kerataconus as well.  I can see without them, and I like it without them better too, but society thinks my vision is defective, that is the view. I have created a lot of bad habits and predicaments because of the lust generated by the eye (i think anyway).  I often think if I never wore glasses, what kind of person would I have been?  Maybe I was meant to have bad eyesight in order to reduce my lust in this lifetime, but oh well, too late now, more bad karma on top of bad karma.  Also, now I am getting migraines too, probably related to the vision. We in this society do a lot of modification to our body to increase chance of survival like wearing makeup, getting tattoos, protein supplements, etc.  Should we be more natural?


pity-party and excuses

related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/54969/16165

https://i.annihil.us/u/prod/marvel/i/mg/4/d0/591c90899fb78/clean.jpg

related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/28509/16165

The mind soul or the subtle body does not 'chose' a suitable host but creates your physical body as per it's own needs. The only thing it choses is its biological parents.
The subtle body dictates the formation of the physical body, not vice versa.

thanks for these words

"recently passed away and been reborn in a certain host of mind-made gods"
